# Issue parsing RSS xml

Tags: c#, rss

I'm having an issue using Linq to XML parsing the following XML.  What I am doing is getting the element checking if it's what I want, then moving to the next.  I am pretty sure it has to do with the xmlns, but I need this code to work with both this style and normal style RSS feeds (no xmlns).  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/">
  <channel rdf:about="http://someurl.com">
    <title>sometitle</title>



XElement currentLocation  = startElementParameter;
            foreach (string x in ("channel\\Title").Split('\\'))
            {
                if (condition1 == false)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (condition2 == false)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is returning null.
                    currentLocation = currentLocation.Element(x);
                }
            }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: XML didn't paste right.

Answer (score 0):

The [XElement.Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method expects an XName.

You're passing through a string, which means it is being implicitly converted to an XName with no attached namespace.

In other words, your `XElement.Element()` calls are asking for elements named `channel` with no namespace, but the `channel` elements in your example XML are in the `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/` namespace due to the `xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"` attribute on `<rdf:RDF>`.

To pull out the channel elements correctly when a namespace is present, you can do this:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/");
currentLocation = currentLocation.Element(ns + "channel");
```

Using the + operator on an XNamespace and a string creates an XName with an attached namespace.

To support both styles of this document, check whether `XDocument.Root` has a namespace with the expected URI value. You can use [XElement.GetDefaultNamespace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace(v=VS.90).aspx) for this.